# Hazelcast fires a listener updated event even though the value has not changed

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Using 3.8.1. Even though the same key and value are put, an updated event is fired? Why?

```
    map.addEntryListener(new EntryUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Updated listener fired oldvalue: " + event.getOldValue() + ", newvalue: " + event.getValue());
        }
    }, true);

map.put("hello", "world");
map.put("hello", "world");
```

Output:

Updated listener fired oldvalue: world, newvalue: world

Updated listener fired oldvalue: world, newvalue: world

Answer (score 1):

A new value is supplied by the `put`. It may have the same bytes as the original. Equality is not the same as identity.
This is a very fine distinction, and ultimately this is an implementation decision.
Aso note, some applications `put` the same value as a way to initiate trigger style processing.

Comment: See also http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#replace-K-V-V-